# Dismiss a UIViewController from bottom to top instead of right to left

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to dismiss a view controller from bottom to top instead of the standard right to left transition. Is this at all possible? Here is the code I have so far:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

CGRect endFrame = self.view.frame;
endFrame.origin.y = screenRect.origin.y - screenRect.size.height;

UIView *aView = [[self.view retain] autorelease];
[self.view.window addSubview:aView];
aView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
                     aView.frame = endFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                     [aView removeFromSuperview];
                 }
 ];
```

This does result in a transition; but the previous view controller does not appear until after the animation since I can't dismiss until after it completes... any ideas?

Comment: Are u using a navigation controller based application ?

Comment: Yes, it is a navigation controller based application

Comment: Did u try presentModalViewController ? you can achieve the animation effect u desired using tat

Comment: This is code to dismiss a view controller... I need that animation when dismissing the controller no when presenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aah, when you presentModalViewController, it automatically hides the view behind. What you need to do is not present and remove, but add the view controllers view as a subview of the main view. Then you just animate the view offscreen, and removeFromSuperview in the competition handler.

Comment: Is this a recommended approach? I have seen articles in the past that advise against adding a UIViewController as a subview to another controller. One view controller per screen.

Comment: This method works perfectly so I will go ahead and accept it as a good solution. It seems that most problems people run into when adding a UIViewController as a subview to another controller are when not using the view controller fullscreen.

Comment: This is a perfectly good solution. On fact, it is the only way until iOS5. When you use the presentModal, dismissModal methods - it is doing something very similar too.